# Как лучше всего организовать управление доступом?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, проектирование, любой-язык, доступ

Рассмотрим абстрактный пример, чтобы было понятно, чего я хочу добиться. Пусть есть мультидиалоги с пользователями. Обычные пользователи могут отправлять, редактировать и удалять свои сообщения. Модераторы могут отправлять, редактировать и удалять свои сообщения и сообщения пользователей, а также кикать пользователей. Администраторы имеют максимальные права.

Я думал использовать модель RBAC — управление доступом на основе ролей: сделать в базе данных таблицы `permissions`, `roles`, `roles_permissions`, `users` и `users_roles`, в permissions у меня бы хранились имена методов (`messages.send`, `messages.edit`, `messages.removeChatUser`, ...), которые может вызывать данная роль, `roles_permissions` связывала бы роли с разрешениями, а `users_roles` — пользователей с ролями. Но я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: пользователь и модератор могут вызывать один и тот же метод `messages.edit`, но пользователь может редактировать только свои сообщения, а модератор — любые. И проблем такого типа немало: модератор может кикать пользователей, но не администраторов, а администратор — всех. Как выход можно, конечно, сделать кучу разрешений типа `messages.edit:can_edit_all`,  `messages.edit:only_by_sender`, но это не выглядит хорошей идеей... Важно: роли могут динамически создаваться и удаляться.

Как можно организовать управление доступом в такой ситуации? Может есть подходы лучше, чем этот?

Answer (score 1):

Кроме RBAC есть еще подход [ABAC](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5_%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2) (attribute-based access control), возможно, он вам подойдет. В принципе, ничто не мешает вам комбинировать оба. В рамках этого подхода вы выдаете каждому пользователю некий атрибут, который будет указывать, кому какое действие можно совершать над пользователем. В вашем случае атрибутом будет сама роль пользователя, но лучше сделать отдельную сущность, потому что в какой-то момент они могут разойтись, например, пользователи будут разделены на подгруппы (скажем, по территориальному признаку), роли у всех будут одинаковые, а доступ к операциям с одной подгруппой будет дана только одному модератору.

Answer (score 0):

Лучше в самом методе делать проверку. Например, редактирование сообщений.
Код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
Метод messages.edit с параметрами (id_Отправителя по умолчанию= UserID, ID_SMS Новый_вариант_сообщения):
   Если id_Отправителя не равно UserID:
    Если UserID[users_roles] = ОбычныйUser:
       вернуть(ошибка2)
    Иначе:
       заменить(ID_SMS, Новый_вариант_сообщения)
```

То есть метод один, а права разные. Просто все зависит от вводных параметров -- если пытаются редактировать чужое сообщение, то запросить права.
Вообще предлагаю вместо текстовых обозночений (такие как 'модератор') использовать цифры (уровень доступа). Например, простой пользователь -- 1, модератор -- 2 и т.д. Так можно будет, например, проверять не ниже ли права модераторских (т.к. у администраторов есть права и модераторов). То есть производить сравнения будет легче.
Так гораздо легче, чем записывать методы куда-то. Если уж и записывать, то надо методы новые делать. А вместо `permissions` нужно сделать `Права_доступа` (цифра от 1 до 3)

Comment: Ваш подход может быть и подошел бы, но я же написал, что роли могут динамически создаваться и удаляться. То есть никаких `= ОбычныйUser` быть не может. Да и потом, нет никакой гибкости в этой системе — права всех ролей жестко захардкодены, а мне нужна возможность их менять.